# Accessing elements using $$ or elements in webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io

I want to access web elements using the `$$` or `elements` command using webdriverio. I know they return array of web elements but I am facing tough time accessing them, probably because I am new to webdriverio.
I tried the below code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',        
},
};
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client
      .init()
      .url(some url)
      .isExisting(selector).then(function(isExisting)) {
      if(isExisting) {
       var bText = this.$$('textarea[name="message_text]')  // this code onwards it is not working
       bText.then(function (res) {
       console.log(res.length);
       console.log(res);
        res.value.forEach(function (elem) {
               return this.click(elem.ELEMENT)
               .setValue(elem.ELEMENT,'some text')
               .keys('Enter')
           })
       })
```

In the above code, I can see the array `res` in console but the `forEach` loop doesn't seem to work. I want to perform `click, setValue and keys('Enter')` for each of the element present in `this.$$('textarea[name="message_text"]')` also  not able to understand why the returned elements are in a form of JSON objects?
If anyone could guide me in right direction that would help!

Comment: did you try and read the documentation? because they explain why

Comment: I read it pretty extensively, but I am not able to access the elements in forEach loop

Comment: You can't execute any commands in a foreach loop like this. In standalone mode all commands are getting executed asynchronously. You need to make sure to handle all promises properly that get returned by the commands. With the wdio testrunner it is much easier since commands are executed synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChristianB's suggestion worked actually,since webdriverio's standalone app is built on top of webdriverjs whose methods return promises we need to resolve them properly.I was able to do this using `map` & `Promise.all` :

```
var bText = this.$$('textarea[name="message_text]') 
   bText.then(function (res) {
   console.log(res.length);
   console.log(res);
var promises = res.map(function (elem) {
           return client
           .elementIdClick(elem.ELEMENT)
           .setValue(elem.selector,'some text')
           .keys('Enter')
       })
return Promise.all(promises)
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 'client' instead of 'this' to select the elements.

```
var bText = client.$$('textarea[name="message_text]')  // this code         onwards it is not working
   bText.then(function (res) {
   console.log(res.length);
   console.log(res);
```

See use of runner here -
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1043

Comment: `this` is attributed to the scope of client variable, so it doesn't make any difference. The real issue was that i was not handling promises properly as pointed out by @ChristianB. Thanks anyway!